# Symfony2 security @Secure annotation not working

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm attempting to use annotations to secure my controllers:

```
namespace Vinny\StreamBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;


class HomeController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="home") 
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_USER")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
     ...
```

But I can't seem to get my controllers to actually be secured. Is there any instances on which this would be ignored?

Comment: A simple thing that might occur: when you add the annotation, but do not do a cache clear, the secure function will seem not to do anything. Only when the system rebuilds and reads changes in annotations, these changes are reflected to final code in cache!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On an almost completely unrelated note, the issue of my problem didn't stem from anything in my configuration or controller, but was an migration mixup from the switch from Symfony 2.0 to Symfony 2.1. I was failing to register the JMSDiExtraBundle which was silently crippling the JMSSecurityExtraBundle's (and others') annotations.

In my AppKernel.php, I had been missing:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
    ...
    new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
    ...
```

With that everything works fine, again.

Comment: ha ha , i was going to tell you that check if your bundle is registered or not

Comment: +1 Don't know where the hell that comes from, but the lack of it was indeed making my security null from a while

Answer (score 0):

You need to try with `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_SUPER` and then see if its secured or not.
`ROLE_USER` is the deafult role applied to all users , so u are allowed

```
@Secure(roles="ROLE_SUPER")
```

Comment: This is true, ROLE_USER is assigned to all users, but I am not authenticated as a user or anyone in this example. Even bumping up the level to ROLE_SUPER or ROLE_ADMIN isn't working, unfortunately.

Comment: @Dan In the symfony debug bar at the lower right hand side corner , click on user image and see what roles you have. Sometimes you are authenticated by your previous session and we don't notice that. In the debug bar you will see whether you are logged in or not

Comment: That also yields no results, sadly. I can guarantee there is no active user sessions because this problem is being replicated through tests, cleared caches, and with an empty user provider. SF just |seems| to be skipping the annotation.