# Annotation JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle doesnt work?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm tring to secure my application `(SF 2.3.7)` with Annotation `(JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle)`. But it does not work. I can access to `addAction` when i'm offline.

My app/config/security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My composer

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
}
```

My AppKernel

```
$bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),

    new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
    new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
    new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
    new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),

    new Intranet\UserBundle\IntranetUserBundle(),
    new Intranet\IntranetBundle\IntranetIntranetBundle(),
);
```

My Controller

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;
use Intranet\IntranetBundle\Entity\Client;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Secure(roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
     */
    public function addAction()
    {
        // stuff
    }
```

For using JMS\Security :

- Update composer
- Update AppKernel
- Add the line `use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;` in controller
- And use annotation

That's all right? What step did I miss?

Comment: can you also post the contents of your security.yml?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but since annotations are cached, have you tried clearing the cache? This may also be necessary in the dev environment..
    app/console cache:clear --env=prod

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see that you don't have `JMSDiExtraBundle`.

Dan, **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665725/symfony2-security-secure-annotation-not-working)**, explained his error/solution which seems to be awfully similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a wild guess, but since annotations are cached, have you tried clearing the cache? This may also be necessary in the dev environment..

```
app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

The only other thing I can think of is some annotation issue. Have you tried using the @Route annotation on the action?